# `cleos get table` not returning vector<string>

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

I declare a vector `vector<string> data` inside a contract.

Contract Code:

```
book.emplace(_self, [&](struct wname &a){
                a.name = fa.pubaddress;
                a.namehash = nameHash;
                a.domain = fa.domain;
                a.domainhash = domainHash;
                a.expiration = expiration_time;
                a.data[0] = fa.data;
            });
```

ABI FILE:

```
,{
          "name": "data",
          "type": "string[]"
        }
```

When I use the `get table` inside cleos I get this information:

```
{
  "rows": [{
      "name": "adam.com",
      "namehash": "649317735385268224",
      "domain": "com",
      "domainhash": "1479432477591207936",
      "expiration": 1583565049,
      "data": []
    },{
      "name": "casey.com",
      "namehash": "1758194651256324096",
      "domain": "com",
      "domainhash": "1479432477591207936",
      "expiration": 1583565049,
      "data": []
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Why does the vector of data not display?

Comment: the issue seems to be with requiring the vector to be a fixed size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push back values into the vector like this:

```
book.emplace(_self, [&](struct wname &a){
                a.name = fa.pubaddress;
                a.namehash = nameHash;
                a.domain = fa.domain;
                a.domainhash = domainHash;
                a.expiration = expiration_time;
                a.data.push_back(fa.data);
            });
```

I don't know what fa is here but. But if  ***fa.data***  contains a string value it will work now.

Comment: @nakomis: Did this solution work for you?

Comment: @RahulMalu do you have similar issue?